# Understanding Google webmaster hAtom errors

Tags: seo, google-search-console, structured-data

A website I am working on is showing tons of errors in the google webmasters tools under the structured data section. Most of the errors are missing author and updated, and there are some missing entry-titles sprinkled in there.

What's confusing me is that the console shows all these errors, but when I select a page that has (in this case) 9 errors, the modal that pops up shows it has the correct information...if I test live data there are 0 errors. The crawl date on the console where it shows 9 errors is only a few days ago, and nothing has changed since then that would affect this.

Please see screenshots below....do I have errors or not? The first picture shows the original errors, the second image is the modal pop up if I select the page, and the third picture shows the results of the live data run.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I do SEO for an events company - and this happens in my own console for event mark-up. Even with numerous errors the rich snippets work just fine. This is despite documentation stating that we're missing 'mandatory' fields.

My recommendation is to **ignore the Search Console.**

Google are in the process of overhauling how they use scraped data. Their next iteration of this project is called **"Rich Cards"**. They've also got a [new validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) in Beta. You could try that one to see if it gives less errors, or different errors. It's a work in progress so your results may vary week to week.

Currently, Rich Cards are only implemented for **movies and recipes** on Google.com. Everything else is using the old rich snippets structure and as I mentioned the official Google documentation for those is out of date. Support for rich snippets and other versions of their data representation is sketchy at best. I wouldn't lose sleep over it if you're following the Schema.org specs. Just be patient and hope that the Rich Cards department gets their act together.